# Segmentation fault in linked list implementation in C++

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, access-violation

I am writing a function in C++ to add a "data" of type 'int' to the end of a linked list.

```
void insert_back()
{
 int no;
 node *temp;
 cout<<"\nEnter the number"<<"\n";
 cin>>no;
 temp = head;
 if(temp != NULL)
 {
         while(temp != NULL)
                    temp = temp->next;
 }

 temp->next = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
 temp = temp->next;
 temp->data = no;
 temp->next = NULL;
```

}

However, at the line, temp->next = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node)), I get an access violation error(segmentation fault). I do not find anything fundamentally wrong. Can you please enlighten me on the issue?

Comment: It does not enter the loop. Instead a new node is initialized and it gets pointed at by temp. My main linked list is "list", so actually i need to give a statement: list = temp; at the end of the function.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the last node of the list, just check if the **next** member is null or not as the **next** member of the last node is null.

In your code, you check **temp** is null or not instead of **temp->next**.

```
while(temp != NULL)
    temp = temp->next;
```

will get the temp be null when the loop is over.

Besides, you should also consider the condition where the head is null.

```
void insert_back()
{
    int no;
    node *temp;
    cout<<"\nEnter the number"<<"\n";
    cin>>no;
    temp = head;
    if(temp != NULL)
    {
        while(temp->next != NULL)
            temp = temp->next;
        temp->next = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp = temp->next;
        temp->data = no;
        temp->next = NULL;
    }else{
        head = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        head->data = no;
        head->next = NULL;
    }

}
```

Comment: the `if (temp != NULL)` isn't helping

Comment: I didn't notice that just now.I think I didn't consider the condition where head is null, do you mean it?

Comment: Yes, and it looks like you have that handled now.  +1

Answer (score 0):

Just before that line executes, `temp` will be null. You then dereference it.

Answer (score 0):

The temp you are referring doesn't exist, temp is NULL. To correct this, instead of using temp!=NULL in the while loop condition, use temp->next!= NULL.

```
 while(temp->next!=NULL)
{
   temp = temp->next;
}

Node* new_node = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));

new_node->data = no;
new_node->next = NULL;
temp->next = new_node;
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has this issue, just check if you have created a Default constructor for your List class or not. In that default constructor " Make your head = NULL ";

Code:

```
class List
{
public:
Node *head;
List()
 {
    head = NULL;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this :-
while(temp->next!=NULL)
Instead of
while(temp!=NULL)

It's such a silly mistake I was facing it and beileve me it took me months to see such a silly fcking error.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
while(temp != NULL)
    temp = temp->next;
```

The above code gets you to the last node in the list. So, you are suppose to add the node to `temp` itself rather than `temp->next`.

```
temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
```

And now the last node's child should be NULL.

```
temp->next = NULL;
```

Comment: This new `temp` will have no connection to the list, so why bother with the loop?

Comment: I have a doubt here.. temp->next gives the address of the next node. So should the new node be referenced by temp->next rather than temp?

Comment: Also, `temp` points to a recently allocated region of memory. Are you sure you want to treat it as a `node`? There are real advantages to using the C++ approach.

Comment: @user2693145 `temp` itself is NULL after exiting while loop. So, you can not do `temp->next`. You can not access members of a struct/class on a NULL reference.

Comment: While exiting the loop, is not temp->data, the last data item and temp->next = NULL?

Comment: @user2693145: *No.* `temp` is null; the last data item, *if it exists*, is something, not null; `temp->data` and `temp-next` are not well-defined, because ***`temp` is null***.

Comment: My doubt is as follows: For the last node, the temp->data is say 3 and temp->next=NULL. Hence during executing of the loop, it actually exits at this stage, where temp->data=3 and temp->next=NULL. How can you say that temp is NULL? Please enlighten and correct me.

Comment: @user2693145: No, it doesn't exit at this stage.  Since `temp != NULL`, it enters the loop body and does `temp = temp->next;`.  And now `temp` is NULL.

Comment: So if I instead set the condition to temp->next!=NULL, is what i am saying correct?